# How to generate TestNg output results before running @AfterSuite annotation

Tags: testng

In my `@AfterSuite` annotation, I am trying to generate Jasper report that takes the `testng-results.xml` as input. But, the issue here is, the `testng-results.xml` gets generated only after executing `@AfterSuite` annotation. I would like to know if it is possible to generate the test results before running `@AfterSuite` annotation. Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

I know there are some answers related to this question [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/31231). But i did not found an exact way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `testng-results.xml` is generated by the TestNG's built-in reporter `org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter`. This reporter is kicked off only at the reporting phase (i.e., only after all the suites have run to completion).

So there's no way that this file can be generated before the `@AfterSuite` annotated method runs to completion.

You could instead build your logic of constructing your jasper based reports via the listener `org.testng.IExecutionListener` in its `onExecutionFinish()` method.

This listener would get called after the reporting phase wherein all the reports have been generated.

The other option is you do the following:

1. Create a new reporter that extends `org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter`
2. Configure TestNG to not run the default reports. For e.g., if you were using Maven as your build tool and were using surefire-plugin, then you could configure surefire-plugin to disable the default reports by adding the following

```xml
<properties>
    <property>
        <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
</properties>
```

3. Wire in the listener you created in (1) via :

   1. `@Listeners` annotation (or)
   2. `<listeners>` tag (or)
   3. Using service loaders [ See [here](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#listeners-service-loader) ]